# Is coercion static or dynamic polymorphism?

Tags: c++, casting, polymorphism, coercion

Parametric polymorphism and overloading are static polymorphism, because the compiler knows at compile-time which function to call.
Subclassing is dynamic polimorphism, beause the function gets determined at run-time. But what is coercion (implicit casting)? Static or dynamic polimorphism?
The compiler knows at compile time which function to call, but the actual cast happens at run-time. Or is that statement wrong?

Comment: Only dynamic_cast is run-time, all others are static and known at compile time.

Comment: why the java tag?

Comment: Type coercion is static (at compile time), and is not polymorphism at all.  It coerces one type to another type, which is a brand new object (probably a temporary unless captured in some way).

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi Because Java supports coercion. But you are right, maybe I shouldn't have included that tag.

Comment: @Eljay Wikipedia says, that coercion is a form of polymorphism (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)#Ad_hoc_polymorphism)

Comment: @Devolus But why is coercion static? If a value is not known at compile-time, how can it be cast to a different type statically?

Comment: @Eljay C++ is not (only) an object-oriented Language and also supports coercion. (E.g. for built-in types or by implementing implicit conversion-constructors/methods)

Comment: @Eljay Coercion is polymorphism in the C++ sense (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/types-of-polymorphisms-ad-hoc-inclusion-parametric-and-coercion) and I never asked about what coercion means in the OO sense!

Comment: The compiler knows at compile-time which coercion function to call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Runtime polymorphism involves (potentially) several distinct bits of machine code being selected from based on some runtime data related to the runtime type of data involved, and that selection happens at runtime.  (I say potentially because you can use virtual dispatch when there's only one concrete derived type, but the runtime mechanism is there to support further types).

With coercion, only one machine code path is required to massage the data into some other type needed by the code then executed - there is *no runtime type-based selection* of the code to execute.  What that one machine code path should be is decided at compile time.